# Split items in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that looks like this;

```
Name: TOR, Length: 162, dtype: object, 
['TOR'], 
0      [W, 9-7]
1      [W, 5-1]
2      [W, 8-2]
3      [L, 1-2]
4      [L, 2-6]
5      [W, 2-1]
```

etc.,

The data comes from a pandas data frame where each team has a column with the above data in it.How can I take this series and turn it into a data frame with one column for the W or L and the other for the score, 9-7? I would even be OK with just dropping everything after and including the ",".

Edit,

Sample from dictionary

```
WinLoss
{'NYY': [[u'L', u'2-6'], [u'L', u'1-3'],....
'MIN': [[u'L', u'3-5'], [u'L', u'6-7'], [u'W', u'10-9']....
'CIN': [[u'L', u'0-1'], [u'W', u'1-0'], [u'L', u'6-7'],
```

If i just

```
Wintable = pd.DataFrame(WinLoss)
```

I end up with the original problem

snippet of data frame;

```
>>> Wintable
           ARI        ATL        BAL        BOS        CHC        CHW  \
0     [L, 1-3]   [L, 0-2]   [W, 2-1]   [L, 1-2]   [L, 0-1]   [W, 5-3]   
1     [L, 5-7]   [W, 5-2]   [L, 2-6]   [W, 6-2]   [L, 3-4]   [W, 7-6]   
2     [L, 8-9]   [W, 1-0]   [L, 3-4]   [W, 4-3]   [W, 3-2]  [L, 9-10]   
3     [W, 5-4]   [W, 2-1]  [L, 4-10]   [L, 2-6]   [L, 2-7]   [L, 5-7]   
4     [L, 0-2]   [W, 6-2]   [L, 6-7]   [L, 6-7]   [L, 0-2]   [L, 3-4]   
5     [L, 5-8]   [L, 1-2]   [W, 3-1]   [L, 0-4]   [W, 8-3]   [W, 5-1]   
6    [L, 2-12]   [L, 0-4]   [L, 2-4]   [W, 5-1]   [L, 6-7]   [L, 1-8]   
7     [L, 4-9]   [W, 4-3]  [W, 14-5]  [L, 7-10]   [W, 7-5]  [W, 15-3]
```

Comment: so each element of the series is a list with two text elements? Like this? `s = pd.Series([['W', '9-7'],['W', '5-1'],['W', '8-2'],['L', '1-2'],['L', '2-6'], ['W', '2-1']])`

Comment: @JDLong, I appears that they are just strings.

Comment: How did you read in the data? I think it'll be easier to start there.

Comment: oh... so the [ are not indicating a list?

Comment: EDIT--

So the data originally came from a dictionary where the key was the team abbreviation "TOR" and the value was a list of size 162, indexed 0 through 162, with each value of the list being another list with the result of the game [W, 9-7].

Comment: Can you show the sample of that dictionary? I think it might be more straight forward to load that dictionary into DataFrame in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

As OP has changed the requirements, I have updated this answer to have a more straight forward approach.

Here is a working solution, probably not the best, but for one-off it does the work.
Rather than converting the Series to workable DataFrame, you should tackle the source and read into DataFrame, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# remember the length of each 'NYC' ... 'CIN' has to be the same as you said, 162
WinLoss = {'NYY': [[u'L', u'2-6'], [u'L', u'1-3'], [u'W', u'2-1']],
'MIN': [[u'L', u'3-5'], [u'L', u'6-7'], [u'W', u'10-9']],
'CIN': [[u'L', u'0-1'], [u'W', u'1-0'], [u'L', u'6-7']]}

# construct an empty DataFrame here
df = pd.DataFrame()

# just loop through the dictionary you have, and write into DataFrame
# another update to shorten the syntax
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k,v in WinLoss.items():
    # name the columns to whatever you want
    df['{} {}'.format(k, 'Win/Loss')] = [r[0] for r in v]
    df['{} {}'.format(k, 'Scores')] = [r[1] for r in v]
```

Sample Results:

```
df
  NYY Win/Loss NYY Scores CIN Win/Loss CIN Scores MIN Win/Loss MIN Scores
0            L        2-6            L        0-1            L        3-5
1            L        1-3            W        1-0            L        6-7
2            W        2-1            L        6-7            W       10-9
```

Comment: Since these columns(the series) are column data within a data frame is there a way to convert them in place? Snipped from the dataframe is in the edits to the original question

Comment: If you don't need to manipulate the `string` of [W, 9-7], there is already a handy `pd.DataSeries.to_frame` to convert Series to DataFrame. However for your case it just transfer the `string` over and the problem still exists

Comment: when I try the approach from above,df = pd.DataFrame(data=[Wintable["BAL"][1:-1].split(',') \
                  for i in Wintable["BAL"].index], columns=['Win/Loss', 'Scores']) I get an error Series has no attribute split

Comment: As OP has been updated, I am going to update my answer for a working solution

Comment: @Josh, please see my updated answer, I believe it will be more straight forward just loop through your dictionary then write the values into the dataframe.

Comment: Not a problem @Josh, glad it helps. I've further shortened the `for/loop` as I believe this would be your expected output :)